# Should I use a lock or ToList()

Tags: c#, collections, locking

To avoid the famous error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

when iterating an `IEnumerator`, should I just use `ToList()` as suggested in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute), or should I use `lock` when updating the list?

My concern is that `ToList()` is simply creating a new list each time, while `lock` will only have a small delay at some points when updating the list.

So, should I use `ToList()` or `lock`?

Comment: lock doesn't help in case the list is changed on the same thread and ToList doesn't make working with the list thread safe

Comment: It is in a WCF service, I better check the threading then. I am always confused about threading and WCF.

Comment: Well web-services in general could mean your code is accessed *in theory* on an arbituary thread.  In my web services I use `ReadWriterLockSlim` to ensure collection reads are in a read-lock, and obviously a write lock when they are updated.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are seeing tells you that you are trying to modify collection while you are enumerating it. The `lock` keyword is applicable in multi-threaded situation and it makes sure your only one thread is in critical section. It has nothing to do with "locking" collection so that you can enumerate it while also modifying it.

The error you are seeing typically occurs with code like below

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
   //Inside this loop now you are enumerating collection
   //This means you can't add or delete anything from items
   items.Add(newItem);  //This will produce the error you are seeing
}
```

This error might also occur if you have one thread enumerating collection while other thread adding or removing from collection. So if you know you have multi-threaded situation then you can use probably use `lock` although it is bit tricky and may impact your concurrency performance and even cause race condition. For multi-threaded situation, using just `ToList` may not be enough either because you need to make sure only one thread has access to collection while you are calling `ToList`. So you may need to use `ToList` along with lock and it may be overall simpler option depending your scenario. To see an example of how to do thread-safe modify-while-enumerate see this answer: [Making a "modify-while-enumerating" collection thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096519/making-a-modify-while-enumerating-collection-thread-safe).

If you know you don't have multiple thread then `ToList` is probably your only option and you don't need `lock` at all. I would also suggest to make sure if you really do need to modify collection while enumerating it. In many cases (but not all), you can do design bit differently to avoid it in first place.

Comment: I do not modify the list while enumerating it, it is a small caching system and sometimes while reading the list some other function is calling the adding method...

Comment: Is this other function running on separate thread? If so, follow the link in the answer. Otherwise just use ToList as mentioned in answer.